# How to plot points on a Bokeh figure object using latitude and longitude?

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial, bokeh

I want to plot some points using latitude and longitude using Bokeh "figure" object. I don't want to use gmap(google maps). I tried the following example but the coordinates are in mercator units. My objective is to use a simpler map tile(like CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA) and plot points and patches using latitude and longitude on a epsg: 4326 projection.

I am very new to geospatial analysis.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA
from bokeh.models import Range1d, ColumnDataSource

mercator_extent = dict(start=-20000000, end=20000000,bounds=None)
x_range = Range1d(**mercator_extent)
y_range = Range1d(**mercator_extent)
fig = figure(tools='wheel_zoom,pan', x_range=x_range,y_range=y_range,x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
fig.axis.visible = True
fig.add_tile(CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA)
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(lat=[ 30.29,  30.20,  30.29],
              lon=[-97.70, -97.74, -97.78])
)

fig.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=15, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)

output_file('simple_map.html')
show(fig)
```

Comment: Try GeoViews (http://geoviews.org), which provides extensive support on top of Bokeh for geospatial analysis.

Comment: Sure, I will try GeoViews. Thanks

Comment: This is covered in the bokeh online tutorial, which is here: https://hub.mybinder.org/user/bokeh-bokeh-notebooks-7lrziue1/notebooks/tutorial/09%20-%20Geographic%20Plots.ipynb